# Get actual div height during jQuery animate

Tags: jquery, resize, jquery-animate

I have some animated graphs. It's cool. But I need to write out the *current* height of the div to another div during the animation (like an analogue timer). I have the starting and the final height, too.
So, maybe a tricky method is OK, where a continuous write out is happening while the animation itself, separately. Unfortunately, I have no idea to do this neither. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the under-documented animate [step](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#step) function ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/NrfTB/1/)):

```
$('#div1').animate({
    height: 500
}, {
    step: function(height) {
        $('#div2')
            .height(height)
            .html( parseInt(height,10) );
    },
    duration: 500,
    complete: function() {}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using jquery

```
$("#div2").text($("#div1").height());
```

you'll have to append it to your animations code, but as you didn't post it I can't guess it!